# Java: handling combined keyboard input

Tags: java, event-handling, keyboard

What is the correct way to separate between <kbd>F1</kbd> and i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> respective <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> within an KeyListener registered behind i.e. a JButton?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    int key = event.getKeyCode();

    logger.debug("KeyBoard pressed char(" + event.getKeyChar() + ") code (" + key + ")");
}
```

.. always gives me 112 for <kbd>F1</kbd>, 113 for <kbd>F2</kbd> and so on. I understand that I can handle it by taking care of the keyPressed() respective for keyReleased for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> / <kbd>ALT</kbd> / etc on my own, but I hope that there is a better way.

Many many thanks!!!

Comment: @ThomasAbraham Please stop focusing on a single editing task - there is plenty more that could be done in this question (tag in the title, thanks at the end, keywords could possibly be highlighted) and any edit should be to attempt to fix *all* of it, not just a single thing. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solution lies in the parent of KeyEvent (InputEvent)

1. Use the isAltDown,isControlDown,isShiftDown methods or
2. Use the getModifiers method

Answer (score 1):

Since KeyEvent extends InputEvent, [isControlDown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown()), [isShiftDown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isShiftDown()) and [isAltDown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isAltDown()).

Answer (score 1):

`KeyEvent`s are probably a bit low-level when dealing with a Swing widget. Instead go through `InputMap` and `ActionMap`.

Answer (score 0):

The key down event is called whenever a key is down, obviously. 
Its not a multiple key down event, and there is no such thing, so there is no keycode for multiple keys being down.

You are just going to have to use a variable to keep track of the crtl key being pressed. This means you are also going to have to use a key up event to keep track of when the control key is released.

In pusedo code:

```
// CRTLKeyCode is whatever the code is for the ctrl key
private boolean ctrlPressed = false;

 onKeyDown(KeyEvent event){
     int key = event.getKeyCode();
     if(key == CRTLKeyCode)
        ctrlPressed = true;
     else if(ctrlPressed && key == 112)
        //Perform your action
 }
 onKeyUp(KeyEvent event){
     int key = event.getKeyCode();
     if(key == CRTLKeyCode)
        ctrlPressed = false;
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I think that it's a lot easier to fetch the status on demand with isXxxDown() as suggested by Midhat/bcash as to manage the status on my own.